# Antoninus Pius coins

Tags: ancient-history, numismatics, ancient-rome

[image][image]

I have looked all over online and cannot find this specific coin. Can anyone help?  We believe they are of Antoninus Pius, but I can’t identify anything on the back, although I believe the winged figure maybe representing Victory? In the pictures they look kind of bronze, but it actually seems to be more of a copper color underneath. [image]

Comment: Any guess on the full writing? If you haven't found this site already, there are [a lot of coin examples here](http://www.wildwinds.com/coins/ric/antoninus_pius/t.html), I'd be surprised if it wasn't *somewhere* in there.

Answer (score 7):

I think that what you have there is actually a 'silver' [Antoninianus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoninianus) minted under Caracalla:

[image: Caracalla AR Antoninianus]

You are correct that the seated figure is Victory (seated facing right on her cuirass, with a shield on her knee).

The text on the obverse reads:

> ANTONINVS PIVS AVG GERM

and on the reverse:

> P M TR P XX COS IIII PP

The text under the seated Victory is:

> VIC PAR

and

> VO XX

is inscribed on her shield.

---

The  Wildwinds site has an [extract](http://www.wildwinds.com/coins/sear5/s6892.html) with the relevant information from the 2000 [Sear catalogue of Roman Coins and Their Values](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pxrdPwAACAAJ).

Comment: Do you know anything about value? Or I f I should leave them the way they are or try to very gently clean them up a little bit?

Comment: @AlaskanMommax2 I don't have the latest Sears catalogue, so I wouldn't be able to put a figure on value (and the catalogue values often bear little value to the actual sale price of the coins!), but I'd say the coin is probably in VF condition from the pictures if that is any help. Cleaning coins is generally discouraged though.

Comment: The bottom picture of the two together is what they really look like. I guess they just looks clean because I use the flash in a dark room on the first 2. I received them made into a pair of earrings and took the earrings apart to get the coins out.

Comment: @AlaskanMommax2 That patina can actually add to the coin's value, rather than detracting from it.

Comment: I know nothing about coins, but love a show called Antiques Roadshow. If I’ve learned nothing else, I know to NEVER touch the finish or patina on anything until I read up first.